# Byte array to image in J2ME?

Tags: image, java-me, arrays

How can I convert a byte array to an image in J2ME ?

Answer (score 0):

Use [createImage(byte[] imageData, int imageOffset, int imageLength)](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Image.html#createImage%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) an example can be seen [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/J2ME/ImmutableImageFromByteArray.htm)